# How can i know if it has list in list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, find

I wanna know if some list contains whole list. for example,

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

from this list, it contains

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

like this. can i do this without any module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

result =  all(elem in list2  for elem in list1)

print(result)# True
```